# animation.css не работает, как настроить

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Я не могу понять как подготовить блок к анимации.

```js
    $('.head__cont').viewportChecker({
        classToAdd: "animated bounceInLeft"
    });

    $('.head__logo').viewportChecker({
        classToAdd: "animated fadeInUp"
    });

    $('.head__backet').viewportChecker({
        classToAdd: "animated fadeInRight"
    });
```

```css
.container-main {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.head {
    padding: 1px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    &__cont{
        height: 100%;
        color: #778089;
    }
    
    &__phone{
        
    }
    
    &__phone-pos{
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-top: 56px;
    }
    
    &__mail-pos{
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 56px;
        
    }
    
    &__backet{
        margin-top: 38px;
        float: right;
    }
    
    &__cost{
        width: 100px;
        border-right: 1px solid #ececec;
    }
    
    &__cost-pos{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    
    &__pay{
        font-size: 0.9em;
        color: #778089;
    }
    
    &__cart{
        width: 83px;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: #dcdcdc;
        border: none;
        color: #778089;
    }
    
    
    &__contactus{
        color: #778089;
        height: 100%;
        
        span{
            line-height: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    }
    
    
    &__contactus-pos{
        margin-top: 15px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-viewport-checker/1.8.7/jquery.viewportchecker.min.js'></script>
<body>
    <div class="container-main">
        <div class="head">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="head__cont">

                        <span class="head__phone head__phone-pos">
                   <img src="" alt="" class="head__smallimg">
                    +1234567892
                </span><span class="head__mail head__mail-pos">
                   <img src="" alt="" class="head__smallimg">
                   
                    mail@example.com
                </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="head__logo">
                        <div class="block__big">
                            <h1 class="block__hbig">
                        <span class="head__orange">Modern</span>
                        <span class="head__black">Shoppe</span>
                        </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="block__less">
                            <h3 class="block__hsmall">
                        <span class="head__smalllogo">Everything for Kids world</span>
                        </h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="head__backet">
                        <div class="head__cost head__cost-pos"><span class="head__pay"><img src="" alt="" class="head__img">$<span class="cost">00.00</span>(<span class="numb">0</span>)</span>
                            <br>
                            <button class="head__cart">Empty cart</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="head__contactus head__contactus-pos">
                            <img src="" alt="" class="head__img"> <span>CONTACT US</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
```

И в итоге анимация работает очень странно. А именно работает !только! когда сжать страницу до мобильной версии и только работает на блоке `head__backet`. Что я делаю не так и как подготовить блок к анимации? Если что-то не понятно в вопросе, спрашивайте я все подправлю.

Comment: Какой блок нужно анимировать, что должно происходить и при каких обстоятельствах?

Comment: ни чего не надо подготавливать , надо просто указать class , вот подробное видео : https://youtu.be/oLCgXG7E8zY

Comment: col-md-4 col-lg-4 добавь и их для разных масштабов

Comment: @Doofy анимация должна происходить при появлении блока в зоне видимости для пользователя, для этого использую 'viewportChecker'

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan к сожалению не помогло. Спасибо